# Partial texts conditional deleting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hello Below are some cells in which the texts are random sized separated with * or with % or with both % and * or with * and % or with more than one % or with nothing and some points.

Cell A1: adlkjadflaskd*kljadkfjasdkfjhas

Cell A2: adslfkjasdfçlkjlkjlksjdflsdfs%309982409

Cell A3: lkaçlaskjdfçklsadjf%sdakdaçsdlkfjaçsl%kdf

Cell A4: lkaçlaskj%dfçklsadjfsdakdaçs%dlkfjaçsl%kd%foi.emb%bl.za*

Cell A5: lkaçlaskj%dfçklsadjfs*dakdaçs%dlkfjaçsl%kd%.rdpdi

Cell A6: lkaçlaskj%dfçklsadjfs*dakdaçs%dlkfjaçsl%kd%e.nem

Cell A7: lkaçlaskj%dfçklsadjfs%dakdaçs%dlkfjaçsl%kd%ensjc.

Cell A8: lkaçlaskj%dfçklsadjfs*dakdaçs%dlkfjaçsl%kd%qsam

Cell A9: alksd.jflskjd

Cell A10: .alksd.jflskjd

Cell A11: alksdjflskjd.

Cell A12: asdsad

How do I write a formula that says the following please?

a) If only * exists (and % dont exist), then delete everything (including it), to the right, and give only the left part as result (example, cell B1 would give as result: Cell B1: adlkjadflaskd)

b) If only % exists (and * dont exist), then delete everything (including it), to the left, and give only the right part as result (example, cell B2 would give as result: Cell B2: 309982409)

c) If both * and % exists, when * comes first and whatever % or * comes after in any order these last 2, then, give as result only what is before the first * and delete the rest after the first * including it (example, cell B3 would give as result: Cell B3: lkaçlaskjdfçklsadjf)

d) If both % and * exists, when % comes first than * or even if another % comes after the first %, then, give as result only what is between the first % that appears with the * if the * is the next symbol after the % (if isnt, dont get result yet) and if between % and * inside the text exists a point (.) not in any other position (beginning/end). If there is %textwithpointinside*, get result, if not, no. If doesnt exist a point in between the text, check rest of the cell if there is another direct combination of %textwithpointinside* to print this first one that happens, and if there happens one result, dont need to look rest of the cell for other results, print only the first one. If there isnt any result between % and * with point inside, leave result in blank. (example, would give as result: Cell B4: foi.emb (because % exists with * while % comes first, and %foi.emb* is the first happening of %textwithpoint* while %bl.za* is the second result, so this second result would be disconsidered and only the first result would go to Cell B4)

e) If both % and * exist (example cells A5 and A6), with % coming first but without any direct %textwithpointinside* or if more than one % exist in the cell (exampe Cell A7) without any *, then, go to the last % of the cell and give as result the last text rightside after the last % but only if there is a point is inside this last text, and leave in blank if pont is before the text (cell A5), after the text (cell A7) or unexistant (cell A8). (example, would give as result: Cell B5: empty (because after last % the point is before the text not inside), Cell B6: e.nem (ok because after the last % there is a point inside the text. And result is not dfçklsadjfs because there was no point on it, otherwise if it had would be it), Cell B7: empty (because after the last % the point is not inside the text but in the end), Cell B8: empty (because after the last % there is no point)

f) If nor * nor % exist, then only copy the full text of the cell as the result if the text contains at least 1 point inside the text (cell A9). If there is a point before the text (cell A10) or after the text (cell A11), leave result in blank. And if there is no point in any place (Cell A12), leave result in blank. (example, would give as result: Cell B9: alksd.jflskjd (because doesnt have % nor * but has text with a point inside), Cell B10: empty (because there is a point before the text), Cell B11: empty (because there is a point after the text), Cell B12: empty, (because dont have * nor % nor a point)

Thank you

Comment: You sample is incorrect, please edit and provide the correct sample first.

Comment: **1. If both * and % exists, when * comes first and then % comes after, then, give as result only what is between the first % that appears with the * and delete the rest for both sides (example, cell B3 would give as result: Cell B3: lksdakdaçs)             2. If both % and * exists, when % comes first and then * comes after, then, give as result only what is between the first % that appears with the * and delete the rest for both sides (example, cell B4 would give as result: Cell B4: dlkfja)** Any difference between these 2 requirements?

Comment: Dear Lee, thanks for your help. Indeed B3 and B4 I were wrong written. I have corrected the full text (I reorganized the wrong information in a new text, a bit bigger but I believe clear now for explaining more detailed the difference which I wanted to say at first. Thank you very much for your valuable help

Comment: Please dont vandalise your post

Comment: Perhaps "vandalizing" is a wrong term, but it's better to just post the final result of the revision than putting the question into a temporary "editing..." state. Take your time, but be sure to improve your post!

Comment: Hello Andrew and fixer, thanks for the suggestion. I realized I edited wrong, due to its complexity. Anyway, thanks. Mr. Lee, I believe now is well explained, is bigger but clear. Sorry for confusion but if you could help would appreciate much. Thanks

Comment: Just some feedback on the question: you aren't likely to attract much interest because it's way too long, way too complicated, and framed as a custom problem of value only to you.  People's reaction will be that SU isn't a free coding shop, hire an Excel wiz to help.  Try to reduce this to a short, simple, generic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your requirements is not very clearly, I will provide part of formula to get the result for A1, A2, A5 and A6.

As shown in the following picture, you can try this formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"*","")))=1,LEFT(A1,FIND("*",A1)-1),IF(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"%","")))=1,MID(A1,FIND("%",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("%",A1)),IF(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))=1,A1,"")))
```

[image]

For A3, A4, please provide the correct information and I will help you finish this formula.

Comment: Hello Lee, have edited and corrected, if you could help would appreciate. Thank you

Comment: Hello Lee, have reduced the size of the text for being easier to read if you could help me finish formula. Thanks